# Error while installing CCDNForumBundle User entity was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, mapping, bundle, fosuserbundle, forum

I would like to say that is possible that I already have found the solution, too bad it's in french. Below is the link to solution.

http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/mappingexception

Getting error below:

> [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
>   The class 'HUPR\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain
>   configur     ed namespaces CCDNForum\ForumBundle\Entity,
>   FOS\UserBundle\Model

I have this Bundle:

```
namespace HUPR\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

    class HUPRUserBundle extends Bundle
    {
        public function getParent() {
            return 'FOSUserBundle';
        }
    }
```

And this is my `app/config/config.yml`:

## Doctrine Configuration

```
orm:
  default_entity_manager: default
  auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
      resolve_target_entities:
          Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface: HUPR\UserBundle\Entity\User
      entity_managers:
          default:
              mappings:
                  CCDNForumForumBundle:
                      mapping:              true
                      type:                 yml
                      dir:                  "Resources/config/doctrine"
                      alias:                ~
                      prefix:               CCDNForum\ForumBundle\Entity
                      is_bundle:            true
```

Comment: Still stucked with this, can't anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, It was needed to map my bundle:

```
mappings: 
FOSUserBundle: ~
HUPRUserBundle:
    mapping:              true
    type:                 annotation
    #dir:                  "Resources/config/doctrine"
    alias:                ~
    prefix:               HUPR\UserBundle\Entity
    is_bundle:            true
CCDNForumForumBundle:
    mapping:              true
    type:                 yml
    dir:                  "Resources/config/doctrine"
    alias:                ~
    prefix:               CCDNForum\ForumBundle\Entity
    is_bundle:            true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I have just encountered this problem. Unfortunately the documentation is not good

Comment: I'm glad of being handy! I had a bad time setting it up.